# how to get array from get to normal array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this and it can contain multiple values:

```
Array
(
    [rpiid] => Array
        (
            [1] => 86
        )

    [sensor_id] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
        )

    [when] => Array
        (
            [1] => 2014-02-24
        )

    [val] => Array
        (
            [1] => 000
        )

    [train] => Array
        (
            [1] => True
        )

    [valid] => Array
        (
            [1] => False
        )

    [button] => update
)
```

Of course, here there is only the number 1 each time but sometimes I have 0, 1, 2 and a value associated. This is because I get this from a GET from multiple forms.

How can I transform this array into

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[rpiid] => 86
[sensor_id] => 1
...
```

Thanks,

John.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can, take a look at this small example:

```
$a = [ 'rpid' => [1], 'cpid' => [2,2] ];

$nodes = [];
foreach($a as $node => $array) { 
  foreach($array as $index => $value) { 
    if(empty($nodes[$index])) 
      $nodes[$index] = []; 

    $nodes[$index][$node] = $value; 
  }
}
```

print_r($nodes):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [rpid] => 1
            [cpid] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cpid] => 2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($first_array as $value => $key){
     $new_array[$key] = $value[1];
}
```

Comment: Actually, he said that here can be more than one value

Comment: You forgot to define array2 before you use it

Answer (score 1):

if your array is $get

```
$newArray = Array();
foreach($get as $secondKey => $innerArray){
    foreach($value as $topKey => $value) {
        $newArray[$topKey][$secondKey] = $value;
    }
}
```